# use GraphQL data when defining const

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

How can I use graphql data when defining a const containing markup data?

I am first defining my markup in const:

```
const videoObject = {
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "VideoObject",
  name: "VIDEO TITLE",
  embedUrl: "{wpLokation.ACFlokationer.video}",
};
```

in the embedUrl I am trying to use data from graphql but it just comes out as plain text: {wpLokation.ACFlokationer.video}

I am furthermore inserting my markup in head using react-helmet:

```
<Helmet>
      <script type="application/ld+json">
      {JSON.stringify(videoObject)}
</script>
 </Helmet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just created a string. Use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) instead:

```
embedUrl: `${wpLokation.ACFlokationer.video}`
```